# C++ - Char Array

Tags: c++, visual-c++, recursion, arrays

Our Teacher said we have to use a 2-D char array, so I created one with:

```
char theArray[14][14] = {'a','b','c','d'} // after 'd', it continues 'e','f' ...
```

afterwards I wanted to send that array into a recursive function (type void) together with two variables that just contain one integer each
in my main file I used:

```
travel(theArray, x, y);
```

to send the array together with the two variables to the function
while my function outside of int main() has

```
void travel (char theArray[][14], int y, int x){...}
```

My compiler tells me something with "converting from char to char[14][14] not possible. And I have absolute no idea what it is trying to tell me. So far I though I have to make the "[][14]" to tell the function the size of the array.

And when I remove the [][14] I get the error on my main file that char and char* arn't compatible.

Ive also tried stuff like setting up a link with  &  and  *  to get around it somehow but so far it didn't work out. If anyone call tell me what it is, that I'm overseeing - thanks!

Comment: Please provide a http://sscce.org/ (with a `main` function) and please copy-paste the entire compiler error message, including the file name and the line number.

Comment: It appears to work as is: http://ideone.com/mKNfWG

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: That post has a bad preferred answer: Does not really answer the question, only gives an example of how it happens in a function call, depending on the prototype.

Comment: The code you show is legal, and works for me (with g++).  There's something else.

Comment: Your function header is OK. The error belongs elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @Deduplicator OK, may be there's a better dupe, propose one! That question is really asked frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me (it compiles without an error or warning and it runs):

```
char theArray[14][14] = {
    {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n'},
    {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n'},
    "abcdefghijklm", "abcdefghijklm", "abcdefghijklm", "abcdefghijklm", 
    "abcdefghijklm", "abcdefghijklm", "abcdefghijklm", "abcdefghijklm", 
    "abcdefghijklm", "abcdefghijklm", "abcdefghijklm", "abcdefghijklm"};
void travel(char theArray[][14], int y, int x){
  (void)theArray; (void)y, (void)x;
}
int main() { 
  int x = 0, y = 0;
  travel(theArray, x, y);
  return 0;
}
```

Maybe you are initializing `theArray` incorrectly. To initialize one element, either specify a string literal (`"abcdefghijklm"`) or a long enough list of characters in braces (`{'x', 3, ...}`).

Comment: Just a list of 196 character constants (e.g. `{ 'a', 'b' ... }`, without the nested braces) would be legal too.